# Can't get custom JPanel to show up on JDialog

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I have developed my own properties type data structure for setting some basic data within an application. I was just using the regular properties, but I wanted the user to be able to edit these and then have notes, display order, and whether or not they are active. Also, to be able to group the different properties.

I created a panel that displays the property with an "Edit" button for them to actually make changes.

Then another panel that loads a group and displays all of the properties for that group.

Both of those panels seem to work fine. Then when I create a JDialog that should load all of the groups into a panel each, I can't get it to display. I have toyed with lots of layouts and no luck. In addition, I will need a scrollpane so when they grow overtime.

I am not quite sure what to do at this point...if I add buttons to the panel, it scrolls just fine, so I assume something is wrong with the Panel I am trying to add.

Here is the property group class:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class SMoKEPropertyGroup {
private String name = null;
private String notes = null;
private int displayOrder = 0;
private boolean active = true;
private LinkedHashMap<String, SMoKEProperty> properties = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public SMoKEPropertyGroup(String name, String notes, int displayOrder, boolean active) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.notes = notes;
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    this.active = active;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

public void setNotes(String notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}

public int getDisplayOrder() {
    return displayOrder;
}

public void setDisplayOrder(int displayOrder) {
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public LinkedHashMap<String, SMoKEProperty> getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public void addProperties(SMoKEProperty property) {
    this.properties.put(property.getName(), property);
}

}
```

Here is the actual property class:

```
public class SMoKEProperty {
private String groupName = null;
private String name = null;
private String value = null;
private String notes = null;
private int displayOrder = 0;
private boolean active = true;
private String displayableName = null;

public SMoKEProperty(String groupName, String name, String value, String notes, int displayOrder, boolean active) {
    super();
    this.groupName = groupName;
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.notes = notes;
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
    this.active = active;
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDisplayableName() {
    return name;

}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

public void setNotes(String notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}

public int getDisplayOrder() {
    return displayOrder;
}

public void setDisplayOrder(int displayOrder) {
    this.displayOrder = displayOrder;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SMoKEProperty \n" + "  groupName=" + groupName + "\ndisplayableName=" + getDisplayableName() + "\nname="
            + name + "\nvalue=" + value + "\nnotes=" + notes + "\ndisplayOrder=" + displayOrder + "\nactive="
            + active + "\n\n";
}

}
```

Here is the panel that displays a property:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class PanelSmokeProperty extends JPanel {

private JLabel lblName = new JLabel();

public PanelSmokeProperty(SMoKEProperty prop) {
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 318, 567, 97, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 25, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");

    lblName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    lblName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblName.weighty = 0.4;
    gbc_lblName.weightx = 0.4;
    gbc_lblName.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_lblName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_lblName.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblName.gridy = 0;
    this.add(lblName, gbc_lblName);

    lblName.setText(prop.getName() + " = ");

    JLabel lblValue = new JLabel(prop.getValue());
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblValue = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblValue.weighty = 0.4;
    gbc_lblValue.weightx = 0.4;
    gbc_lblValue.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_lblValue.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_lblValue.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblValue.gridy = 0;
    add(lblValue, gbc_lblValue);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnEdit = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnEdit.weighty = 0.2;
    gbc_btnEdit.weightx = 0.2;
    gbc_btnEdit.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_btnEdit.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_btnEdit.gridx = 2;
    gbc_btnEdit.gridy = 0;
    add(btnEdit, gbc_btnEdit);
}
}
```

Here is the panel to show a property group:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class PanelSmokePropertyGroup extends JPanel {

public PanelSmokePropertyGroup(SMoKEPropertyGroup propGroup) {

    this.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, propGroup.getName(), TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 1133, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 100, 176, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JLabel lblLabelForDescription = new JLabel("Label for Description");
    lblLabelForDescription.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 75));
    lblLabelForDescription.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblLabelForDescription = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblLabelForDescription.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_lblLabelForDescription.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_lblLabelForDescription.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblLabelForDescription.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblLabelForDescription.gridy = 0;
    this.add(lblLabelForDescription, gbc_lblLabelForDescription);

    JPanel panelForProperties = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_panelForProperties = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panelForProperties.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc_panelForProperties.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc_panelForProperties.gridx = 0;
    gbc_panelForProperties.gridy = 1;
    add(panelForProperties, gbc_panelForProperties);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panelForProperties = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panelForProperties.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    gbl_panelForProperties.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0 };
    gbl_panelForProperties.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_panelForProperties.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    panelForProperties.setLayout(gbl_panelForProperties);

    GridBagConstraints gbc_panelProperty = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_panelProperty.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_panelProperty.gridx = 0;
    // int scrollPaneHeight = (int) scrollPane.getBounds().getHeight();
    // panelForProperties.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(749,
    // scrollPaneHeight));
    int y = 0;
    for (SMoKEProperty p : propGroup.getProperties().values()) {
        PanelSmokeProperty panelPropery = new PanelSmokeProperty(p);
        gbc_panelProperty.gridy = y++;
        panelForProperties.add(panelPropery, gbc_panelProperty);
    }

}

public static void main(String... args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
    PanelSmokePropertyGroup panel = new PanelSmokePropertyGroup(DialogProperties.getGroups().get("Group 1"));
    // PanelSmokePropertyGroup2 panel2 = new
    // PanelSmokePropertyGroup2(DialogProperties.getGroups().get("Group
    // 2"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    // frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

And finally, here is the JDialog that uses all that and won't show those panels properly:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class DialogProperties extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DialogProperties dn = new DialogProperties();
        dn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dn.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public DialogProperties() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    setTitle("System Properties");
    setModal(true);
    setBounds(100, 100, 869, 608);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 851, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 561, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_contentPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_contentPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_contentPanel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_contentPanel.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, gbc_contentPanel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPanel.columnWidths = new int[] { 1, 800, 0 };
    gbl_contentPanel.rowHeights = new int[] { 477, 50, 0 };
    gbl_contentPanel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gbl_contentPanel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    contentPanel.setLayout(gbl_contentPanel);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    // scrollPane.setBounds(12, 13, 1235, 382);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 0;
    contentPanel.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_okButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_okButton.ipady = 45;
    gbc_okButton.ipadx = 45;
    gbc_okButton.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
    gbc_okButton.gridx = 1;
    gbc_okButton.gridy = 1;
    contentPanel.add(okButton, gbc_okButton);

    okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);

    for (SMoKEPropertyGroup group : getGroups().values()) {
        PanelSmokePropertyGroup p = new PanelSmokePropertyGroup(group);
        panel.add(p);
    }

}

public static LinkedHashMap<String, SMoKEPropertyGroup> getGroups() {
    LinkedHashMap<String, SMoKEPropertyGroup> groups = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        SMoKEPropertyGroup g1 = new SMoKEPropertyGroup("Group " + i, "some notes", 0, true);
        for (int p = 1; p <= 15; p++) {
            g1.addProperties(new SMoKEProperty(g1.getName(), "Property " + p, "something", "notes", 0, true));
        }
        groups.put(g1.getName(), g1);
    }
    return groups;
}
}
```

Comment: Please shrink down your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue. There is **lots** of unnecessary code shown - for example, to mention two issues, there are two main methods, and there is no `JFrame` in the code where you say "here is the JFrame".

Comment: The root of the problem is using `null` layouts. That leads to those panels having preferred size (0, 0), which causes problems when placing them to containers. Learn to use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) instead, that's how swing was designed to be used.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: My apologies...it isn't a JFrame, it is a JDialog. The other main methods are there for testing purposes to check each panel as I went. They can be ignored. It is a hard problem to shrink down because you need to see how it grows with the different panels. The first 2 classes are just there to support the building of the panels.

Comment: @KonstantinosFotiadis: You should change the title then, else this important information is hard to see. Also try to cut down the shown code, some of it (like the empty `save()-method`) seems to not be important to the problem. Making a [mcve] often enough helps yourself to locate the error, while writing the questions. :)

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. But other than that save method, I am pretty sure you need everything else. I figured the extra "main" methods in the JPanels would help make it easier for those to see how they load fine, but as you step out to the main JDialog, it fails. I will clean up those areas now. Thank you!

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Over 75% of the code can be removed and it doesn't compile. Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: I understand the MCVE but I don't understand how I can remove 75% of this code and still get the same thing to work. I never thought about moving the code to a new project, and I see what you mean about that. Is there a way to post a zip of the files? I can't seem to figure this out for anything.

Comment: new code is updated...it compiles if you copy those 5 classes to a project...tried removing as much as possible...also added in some layouts, but still can't seem to get it to work

Comment: A GUI builder wrote the code for you? Personally, I'm not going to go over so much excess code for a simple layout problem. I suggest you start from scratch - create a dialog and add to it what you need 1 by 1 to see where it breaks. Then post the code when it does.

Comment: Also, when I run your code I see a dialog displaying properties with edit buttons. Not sure if that's what's not working for you.